# Drop-down menu scraping ruby

Tags: ruby, drop-down-menu, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to learn how to look at a drop-down menu to store the links to which the menu refers, using Ruby. I'm using Mechanize gem.
The site is this:
http://www.terna.it/SistemaElettrico/TransparencyReport/Load/ActualLoad.aspx

I found only this guide:
http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/csurgeries-mechanize/

Can you help me to get the links for each year and each month?

Thanks

```js
require 'mechanize'
require 'openssl'
require 'open-uri'

home_url = 'http://www.terna.it/SistemaElettrico/TransparencyReport/Load/ActualLoad.aspx'

SELECT_FIELD_NAMES = {
  'Year'=>'dnn$ctr5810$TernaViewDocumentView$cbAnno',
   'Month' => 'dnn$ctr5810$TernaViewDocumentView$cbMese'
}

#Initialize Mechanize
mech = Mechanize.new
page = mech.get(home_url)

terna_form = page.form('dnn$ctr5810$TernaViewDocumentView$cbAnno')

terna_form = 'ruby mechanize'
puts terna_form
puts mech.page.class    
form = mech.page.forms[0]
puts form.class
puts form.fields.map{|f| f.name}.join("\n")

puts "---------"
year_field ={}

form['name'] = SELECT_FIELD_NAMES["Year"]
puts form['name']

form[SELECT_FIELD_NAMES['Year']] = 2017  


#Submitting a form
list =[]
list = form.submit(form.button_with(:value=>'Cerca'))
list.each do |e|
    puts e
    
end

puts "the end"
```

Comment: What does your code return currently?

Comment: This is the object list which I print: cache-control
private
content-type
text/html; charset=utf-8
content-encoding
gzip
vary
Accept-Encoding
server
Microsoft-IIS/8.5
set-cookie
language=en-GB; path=/; HttpOnly
date
Mon, 08 Oct 2018 07:28:37 GMT
content-length
57257. While i want something like #=> [2018,2017,2016]